# Namespace ‘data.table’ is not available and has been replaced

Tags: r, namespaces, data.table, r-package

During the latest builds of my R package the following R CMD CHECK warning occurs:

```
Found the following significant warnings:
  Warning: namespace ‘data.table’ is not available and has been replaced
```

The strange thing is that I do not use `data.table` in Depends/Imports/Suggests in my DESCRIPTION file. It is also not a dependency of any package I import. May be a dependency of a dependency?
  I do not know which change introduced this warning. Searching did not result in any useful solution.

```
Depends: R (>= 3.0.0)
Imports: mgcv, 
         MASS, 
         stats,
         ggplot2,
         cowplot
```

Comment: some info could be useful, 1. `sessionInfo()` from your base R, 2. do you run check from console, 3. if your package is public you can share link

Comment: The error appeared on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Just tried it on macOS 10.12 and the error did not appear. Concluding that it is machine related. I will do your suggested actions later on @jangorecki

Answer (score -1):

Install the package "data.table". The error not appear in R CMD check procedure.